# '$' is not defined no-undef reactjs ajaxcall

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying to display json data in a table format based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40347411/how-to-display-json-data-with-reactjs-in-the-table). Everytime I run this, it shows this error `Line 15:  '$' is not defined  no-undef`. I am starting the ajax call in line 15. I've tried adding  `const $ = window.$;` on the top of the code, but that doesn't solve anything.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
      super() 
        this.state = {
          data: []
        }
      
    }
    componentDidMount() {
      $.ajax({
         url: "http://www.mocky.io/v2/5c3f2a6c3500004d00ec3789",
         type: "GET",
         dataType: 'json',
         ContentType: 'application/json',
         success: function(data) {
           
           this.setState({data: data});
         }.bind(this),
         error: function(jqXHR) {
           console.log(jqXHR);
         }.bind(this)
      })
    }
    render() {
      
          
      return (
        <table>
        <tbody>{this.state.data.map(function(item, key) {
               
                 return (
                    <tr key = {key}>
                        <td>{item.name}</td>
                        <td>{item.post}</td>
                        <td>{item.country}</td>
                        <td>{item.contact}</td>
                    </tr>
                  )
               
               })}</tbody>
         </table>
      )
    }
  }
  


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Any help with the error?

Comment: It looks like not able to find `jQuery` library. Please import `jQuery` library before your script code loaded in DOM.

Comment: Did you imported jQuery ? `import jQuery from 'jquery'`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When using create-react-app, First You need to install the Jquery package like this.

For **Mac**

```
sudo npm install jquery --save
```

For **Windows**

```
npm install jquery --save
```

Now in the JS files you can use jquery

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

Comment: Is `sudo` needed to install a non-global node dependency?

Comment: that resolved the error. But my table isn't showing up in the browser

Comment: sudo is used in Mac environment, when you use Windows try without sudo (npm install jquery --save )

Comment: I had to use `import * as $ from 'jquery';`. The import statement in the answer resulted in an error for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include jQuery library.

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

make sure jquery package is installed.

Comment: that resolved the error. But my table isn't showing up in the browser

Comment: use `console.log` to see whether the state is updated properly

Comment: It doesn't hit the ajax success function.

Comment: used datatype jsonp instead of json. That solved the problem

Comment: put a `console.log(data);` inside your `success function` to see if your data arrives as it should be. if it is okay then it has something to do with your state update

Comment: yeah tried that. That didn't solve the problem either. Just found that changing data-type from "json" to "jsonp" makes thing work

Answer (score 1):

You might not even need jQuery in React, the `fetch` API exposes by the browser just works fine. Rather than installing the entire jQuery library to just handle Ajax request, I would go instead with `axios` which in my opinion is lightweight than jQuery.