# How do I display this json data with reactjs on my HTML page

Tags: html, node.js, json, reactjs

I am very new to web design (literally no prior knowledge) and is currently trying to create a website which pulls data from my MySQL database using Nodejs and display it on my HTML page with Reactjs. Any help would be highly appreciated

I previously copied the code from [how to display json data with ReactJs in the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40347411/how-to-display-json-data-with-reactjs-in-the-table), but when I used my URL from my localhost server with the JSON data in it it just shows me the error "TypeError: this.state.data.map is not a function".

this is my app.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
      super() 
        this.state = {
          data: []
        }

    }
    componentDidMount() {
      $.ajax({
         url: "http://localhost:4000/stockin",
         type: "GET",
         dataType: 'json',
         ContentType: 'application/json',
         success: function(data) {

           this.setState({data: data});
         }.bind(this),
         error: function(jqXHR) {
           console.log(jqXHR);
         }.bind(this)
      })
    }
    render() {


      return (
        <table>
        <tbody>{this.state.data.map(function(item, key) {

                 return (
                    <tr key = {key}>
                        <td>{item.No}</td>
                        <td>{item.Stocktype}</td>
                        <td>{item.Binid}</td>
                        <td>{item.Stockid}</td>
                    </tr>
                  )

               })}</tbody>
         </table>
      )
    }
  }

  ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

And this is my json data

```
{"stockin":[{"No":1,"Stocktype":"XM21","Binid":"1234124","Stockid":"135215215","Datestockin":"2019-05-05T16:00:00.000Z","Quantity":52,"Remarks":"Good stock"},
{"No":2,"Stocktype":"XM22","Binid":"2352342","Stockid":"123456721","Datestockin":"2019-05-05T16:00:00.000Z","Quantity":21,"Remarks":"Good stock"},
{"No":3,"Stocktype":"screw","Binid":"2432342","Stockid":"123456721","Datestockin":"2019-05-05T16:00:00.000Z","Quantity":23,"Remarks":"Good stock"},
{"No":4,"Stocktype":"screw","Binid":"1325123","Stockid":"242353223","Datestockin":"2019-04-30T16:00:00.000Z","Quantity":32,"Remarks":"Screws for bins"}]}
```

I wish to be able to display the data in a table form on my HTML website in the end.

Comment: Your response data is not an array directly. You'll probably have to do `this.setState({ data: data.stockin })`

Comment: Exactly, and also is not recommendable using jquery with react, you can try to do the same with axios

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb Thank you so much for that, I did what you said and now its working perfecttly! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change like below in your code

```
success: function(data) {
             this.setState({data: data.stockin});
         }.bind(this),
```

then it will work correctly at all times

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

May be the issue is initially the data is empty so what you have to so is check the length of `data` like

```
{this.state.data.length  == 0 && <div>No data found</div>} 
{this.state.data.length > 0 && 
 <table>
    <tbody>{this.state.data.map(function(item, key) {

             return (
                <tr key = {key}>
                    <td>{item.No}</td>
                    <td>{item.Stocktype}</td>
                    <td>{item.Binid}</td>
                    <td>{item.Stockid}</td>
                </tr>
              )

           })}</tbody>
     </table>
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `.map` on `data.stockin` instead.

```
      return (
        <table>
        <tbody>{this.state.data.stockin.map(function(item, key) {

                 return (
                    <tr key = {key}>
                        <td>{item.No}</td>
                        <td>{item.Stocktype}</td>
                        <td>{item.Binid}</td>
                        <td>{item.Stockid}</td>
                    </tr>
                  )

               })}</tbody>
         </table>
```

But instead of doing that, in your `componentDidMount`, you can do this in the success callback...

```
this.setState({data: data.stockin});
```

By doing this, you're getting rid of a possible error in your `render` method when checking for `this.state.data.stockin.map`, as `this.state.data` is could be empty at the time of the call.