# How to display json data in a reactjs component

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I'm new to react. I dont know how to import json data in one of my component.

This is my json data:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "firstname": "abc",
        "lastname": "xyz",
        "phone": "+91 789654123",
        "email": "abcyz@gmail.com"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "firstname": "def",
        "lastname": "uvz",
        "phone": "+91 123456987",
        "email": "defvu@gmail.com"
    }
]
```

Here is list Component :

```
<Container>
  <Grid>
    <Grid.Row>
      <Grid.Column>
        <Header>List</Header>
        <List>
          <List.Item block>
            <List.Content>FirstName and Last Name</List.Content>
            <List.Content>Phone</List.Content>
          </List.Item>
        </List>
      </Grid.Column>
    </Grid.Row>
  </Grid>
</Container>
```

Can anyone help me in displaying the list? Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display json data with ReactJs as table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40347411/how-to-display-json-data-with-reactjs-as-table)

Comment: @GoodSamaritan - I want make a contact list. want to display json data in data.json and want to import in contactlist

Comment: Sorry, Unfortunately clicked ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can import contacts from your data.json, and use the map() to iterate and display contacts.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Container, Grid, Header, List } from "semantic-ui-react";
import contacts from './data.json';

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Grid>
          <Grid.Row>
            <Grid.Column>
              <Header>List</Header>
              <List>
                {contacts.map(el => {
                  return (
                    <List.Item  key={el.id}>
                      <List.Content>
                        {el.firstname} {el.lastname}
                      </List.Content>
                      <List.Content>{el.phone}</List.Content>
                    </List.Item>
                  );
                })}
              </List>
            </Grid.Column>
          </Grid.Row>
        </Grid>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Playground:

https://codesandbox.io/s/so-semantic-ui-jfobr

But I think using Table component from semantic-ui-react would be a better for this.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {  Table } from "semantic-ui-react";
import contacts from './data.json';

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Table singleLine>
        <Table.Header>
          <Table.Row>
            <Table.HeaderCell>Id</Table.HeaderCell>
            <Table.HeaderCell>Fullname</Table.HeaderCell>
            <Table.HeaderCell>Phone</Table.HeaderCell>
            <Table.HeaderCell>Email</Table.HeaderCell>
          </Table.Row>
        </Table.Header>

        <Table.Body>
          {contacts.map(el => {
            return (
              <Table.Row key={el.id}>
                <Table.Cell>{el.id}</Table.Cell>
                <Table.Cell>
                  {el.firstname} {el.lastname}
                </Table.Cell>
                <Table.Cell>{el.phone}</Table.Cell>
                <Table.Cell>{el.email}</Table.Cell>
              </Table.Row>
            );
          })}
        </Table.Body>
      </Table>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Playground for Table version:

https://codesandbox.io/s/so-semantic-ui-28rq9

Docs:

https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Is it possible to create search for the list?

Comment: @Sanjana  if you mean in table,  semantic-ui-react's Table component does not built-in search functionality. Of course it can be manually done, but some other UI frameworks have this built-in functionality like antd react. https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-head

Comment: @Sanjanaf or manual search, I found a sample here: https://codepen.io/Natarajah/pen/mAGQpw

Comment: Just search in google,  for "react search in list", you will see lots of tutorials.

Comment: thank you so much for helping me. Could you please help me how to execute successfully when fetching through the api link without any error

Comment: @Sanjana you had better to ask a new question about that. I will try to help in that question.

Comment: sorry, I'll ask in another question

Comment: what if we want to add search, sort and filter to this list? how do we do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to import that data to your component from another file you can basically export the object where the data exists.

`data.js`

```js
export default [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "firstName": "abc",
        "lastName": "xyz",
    },

    {
        "id": 2,
        "firstName": "def",
        "lastName": "uvz",
    }
]
```

In your react component you can then import your json data by doing

```js
import data from './data.js'
```

You will need to iterate over your json data to pass necessary information to your component

```js
{data.map(person => {
   return (
    <List.Item block key={person.id}>
       <List.Content>
         {person.firstName} and {person.lastName} 
       </List.Content>
     <List.Content>{person.phone}</List.Content>
    </List.Item>
   )
})}
```

**Heads up!**
List elements need a key property as well otherwise react wil throw an error

This will create a `List.Item` component for each data entry you have regarding the people and then by accessing the `firstName`, `lastName`, `phone`on person object you will be able to pass that data to your component.

**Example**

https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-chebyshev-djxq0?fontsize=14

Comment: Thanks it really works!.. Thank you for explaining through example

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to import JSON data within a React component:

1. Use ES6 imports and exports
2. Add the JSON data in a file within your `public` folder, assuming you initialized your project with Create React App, then fetch said data within your `componentDidMount()` method, and lastly add the fetched data to your component's state.
3. If the data is static, you could just add it to your component's state when you initialize your component.

**Implementation 1:**

Add your JSON  data in file, for example `People.js`:

```
const peopleData = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "firstname": "abc",
        "lastname": "xyz",
        "phone": "+91 789654123",
        "email": "abcyz@gmail.com"
    },

    {
        "id": 2,
        "firstname": "def",
        "lastname": "uvz",
        "phone": "+91 123456987",
        "email": "defvu@gmail.com"
    }
];

export default peopleData;
```

Then within your component, import it like so:

```
// myPeopleData will contain your json data
import myPeopleData  from '<Relative_Path>/People.js';
```

For more information about ES6 imports and exports check out this great [cheatsheet](https://hackernoon.com/import-export-default-require-commandjs-javascript-nodejs-es6-vs-cheatsheet-different-tutorial-example-5a321738b50f).

**Implementation 2:**

1. Add a file within your `public` directory containing your JSON data, lets assume it's called `people.json`
2. Within your component, add in the `componentDidMount()` lifecycle method then fetch your data.
3. Add your fetched data to your component's state.

Your component might look something along the lines of:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Container, Grid, Header, List } from "semantic-ui-react";

class MyComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    peopleData: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
      fetch('./people.json')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({ peopleData: data }));
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Lastly, **Implementation 3**:

Within your component just add your data as part of it's default state:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Container, Grid, Header, List } from "semantic-ui-react";

class MyComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    peopleData: [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "firstname": "abc",
        "lastname": "xyz",
        "phone": "+91 789654123",
        "email": "abcyz@gmail.com"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "firstname": "def",
        "lastname": "uvz",
        "phone": "+91 123456987",
        "email": "defvu@gmail.com"
      }
    ]
  };

  render() {
    ...
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Regardless of the approach you take to import your JSON data, you will need to map through your resulting array within your `render()` method. For more information about `Array.protoype.map()` method check out MDN's [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) as well as React's [Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#embedding-map-in-jsx) for mapping through lists and rendering list items. Both of which are fantastic resources.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thank you so much. This works!.. Thank you for explaining briefly with example and documentation :)

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping me in knowing more about reactjs and how to implement json data into the component and how to retrieve the data into the component, I learnt alot. Thank you so much for assisting me :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  loadedList: [],
  lists: [],
};
  }

componentDidMount() {
  
  // after 3001/ write your .json file directory
  
  axios.get('http://localhost:3001/../static/data/terrifdata.json')
      .then(response => {
       this.setState({
         lists: response.data,
         loadedList: response.data,
         isLoading: false
        })
    })
 }

<div>
{loadedList.map((postDetail, index) => {
                    return (
                  <h5>
                     {postDetail.name}
                  </h5>
                  )}
               }
</div>
```