# Display json data stored into array in table format using React

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, frontend, web-frontend

I have configured a react website to receive json data and store it into an array in the format depicted in the attached image.  How would I go about displaying this information in a table format?[json data stored in array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gj7Mp.png)

Comment: This should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40347411/how-to-display-json-data-with-reactjs-as-table

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use property names, you could do something like that :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const App = () => {
  const data = [
    { id: 0, value: "item 1" },
    { id: 1, value: "item 2" },
    { id: 2, value: "item 3" }
  ];
  const keys = Object.keys(data[0]);

  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          {keys.map(key => {
            return (
              <th>
                <td>{key}</td>
              </th>
            );
          })}
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <tr>
                {keys.map(key => (
                  <td>{item[key]}</td>
                ))}
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Note that all of your items need to have the same properties (here 'id' and 'value') for this to work.

Here is [the repro on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-functional-boilerplate-16-13-1-fma6vx)

If you need something better then you should look for a package made for this, there's plenty on internet.